# Should I put if(variable < 10) in own method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods

I have a check in a loop where I have to check if the number of occurrence is less than 10 which could be written as either

```
 if(occ < 10){

 }
```

or

```
 if(checkIfOccurencyIsLessThan10(occ)){
         values.add(current+"0"+occ);
    }
     else{
          values.add(current+occ);
    }
```

I'm reading Clean Code a handbook of agile software craftsmanship, where they say a method should do the least amount, and code should be hacked up into more pieces. Is this necessary right here? I'm trying to get a better grasp on how long a method should be, and how much it should be doing.

Comment: I was once recommended by my manager to use something like this:
checkIfOccurencyIsLess(occ,10)

Comment: You shouldn't be "hacking it up into more pieces" just for the sake of it - put it in its own method if you can give it a name that adds semantic value (i.e. if it reduces the cognitive load for someone reading your code).  That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I think that's getting a little small. Especially since you have `10` right in the method name! That detracts from some of the benefits to segregating it off into its own method.

Comment: This depends a lot on the usages of this code and the code around it. You are looking for a code review, not for an answer to a question. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com but you would need to include a more complete code sample

Comment: If you put it on its own method, you can give the method a name that explains _why_ you're doing that comparison, and that has value.

Comment: Carcigenicate, yeah that makes sense. I'll just have the if test instead, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if this condition is spread across multiple pieces of code, and if this check could change in the future to include checking additional edge cases. If both of those things are true or could be true, then sure, extracting the check to its own function is wise. However, I would definitely say you should rename the function to not specify the functions implementation, because that defeats the purpose of being able to change out the conditional, right? Naming it something like `occurenceNeedsZero` is a much more flexible solution. Because if you come up with other use cases that need checking you can add them to this function as well!

However, if your question is "should I always make a simple conditional check such as "is x < 10" into its own function, then I would say no. That would be overengineering, in my opinion. Functions should be used to 1) separate logical portions of code, 2) increase readability, or 3) extract small pieces of code that are spread across multiple locations and likely to change in the future, as it simplifies future refactoring.

There are probably more cases than those 3, but those are the big ones.

Comment: The occurenceNeedsZero made more sense to use. The test does get used three times in the loop, which is why I'll implement it as it will increase the readability for the most part

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a static final variable to store this `10`, instead hard code.

If there are other places need to check if `occ < 10`, you need extract it as a method. Otherwise it is unecessary.